# Can somebody recommended a tour for the Amazon in Ecuador?

Tags: amazon-river, tours, ecuador

I'm heading to Ecuador next spring and I'm hoping someone can recommend a good tour that they took and how much it cost for how many days.  I've seen some with trekking and canoes etc.  My dates are flexible but I'm looking for something in the 4-7 day range.

Comment: Would this tour take you to Colombia, Peru, Brazil, or a combination of them? There isn't much Amazon in Ecuador - plenty of other rainforests though.

Comment: I think a combination of them.  I will be traveling south from Costa Rica through Columbia, Ecuador, and Peru most likely.  So any of those places I'd be interested in taking a tour.  I read that if I want to see the Amazon Rainforest that there are some good tours that launch from Ecuador so that was my departure point in the question.

Comment: I think your best bet if you're travelling the west coast of South America is to make your way to Iquitos, Peru. Most of the other alternatives for amazon trips start in Brazil. You certainly don't need to book anything in Ecuador, either.

Comment: I had to rush through Ecuador last November, and I wish I'd gone up the big volcano, it looked spectacular.  Are you looking for just Amazon, or mountains, and what about city - will you rush through Quito or spend some time there?  Got a few answers ready when we get this defined ;)

Comment: Cotopaxi, that's the one I was thinking of.

Comment: @Mark I'm looking for anything worthy of seeing :)  Doesn't just have to be the Amazon jungle.  I will simply be passing through Ecuador on my way to Brazil and I love adventure.  I don't know a lot about the area so I'm hoping to learn about what's worth seeing, and how much time would be appropriate to get a good feel for each place!

Comment: Quito is fine in a couple of days, stay at Secret Garden hostel if you haven't got a place, they offer free walking tours and salsa lessons ;)  From there, ask the staff as it's an easy day trip to a nearby market town and the big center marking the Equator, depending how much of a geography nut you are ;)  They'll also tell you about their other hostel on Cotopaxi, the views look amazing.  If going into Peru by bus, stop off at Mancora for a couple of days at the beach (The Point hostel) - you won't want to leave, especially if you're there at the full moon...

Comment: wow great suggestions :D This is perfect information because of how specific it is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this site is only in German, but maybe you understand some basic information, because there are also lot of pictures in it:

http://www.hauser-exkursionen.de/amerika/eck12von_den_anden_zum_amazonas.php

It is a 18 day tour in Ecuador that leads from the Andes until Amazon. I know you have only time for 4-7, but maybe you can get some suggestions from it.

Here is another German site which offers a lot of different tours in Ecuador that are not necessarily Trekking tours like Hauser:

http://www.studienreisen.de/list.php?land_id=89&studreise_reisetyp_id=&fk_veranstalter_id=&studreise_reisethema_id=&datum_ab=01.09.2011&datum_bis=--.--.----&btn_short_search=suchen!

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd come back and give this question another try.

http://www.gapadventures.com/trips/exploring-the-amazon-rainforest/SEL4D/2011/ is GAP Adventures' sole Amazon tour IN Ecuador if you just search tours less than 7 days.  4 days in duration, it takes you from Quito to Coca and their jungle lodge, and back. Includes motorized canoe, caiman hunting by flashlight (you look for the eyes ;)) and a naturalist guide to tell you about the environment and animals around.